# Use class instead of sqlite in android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I think about putting my 1000 lines of db records in class in android in order to better prevent from stealing the sqlite database, which i belive it's a way easier way to solve the issue of stealing instead of using the encrypting the sqlite db. My data will allways be fixed no changes will be made. So i was more interested in how will that react on the speed of the app getting the data from a java class instead of sqlite , or if anyone can show me an example of easy way to encrypt the db, i am also usng SqliteAssistHelper so i don't think i can move my assets folder to the root of my app

Answer (score 1):

I'd just encrypt every row that you put put into your database.

usage:

```
    Crypto cr = new Crypto();
    cr.generateKey();
    byte[] enc = cr.encrypt("some data string"); // enc is your encrypted string
```

Crypto.java:

```
public class Cryptooo {

SecretKeySpec key = null;
byte[] ciphertext;

 public void generateKey()  {

 String passphrase = "3xtr3meDiFficUltp@ss";

 MessageDigest digest = null;
 try {
     digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 digest.update(passphrase.getBytes());
 key = new SecretKeySpec(digest.digest(), 0, 16, "AES");

 byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();



 }


public byte[] encrypt(String string)    {
    Cipher aes = null;
    try {
        aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

    aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    ciphertext = aes.doFinal(string.getBytes());


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ciphertext;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] ciphertext)    {

    Cipher aes = null;
    String cleartext =null;


    try {
        aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        cleartext = new String(aes.doFinal(ciphertext));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cleartext;
}

}
```

Comment: the problem is when i try to get the column value back i get null
 byte [] b=rowGetter.getBlob(rowGetter.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_titles));
    
  String DataKey=cr.decrypt(b);

and in the database it is of type blob

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with this process [sqlcipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/)?
Take a look at this also: [sqlite-encrypt](https://github.com/lendylongli/android-sqlite-encrypt). I think this is a better approach that the one you are asking about.